# Amount of force required it to tip over a cone

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, geometry

Say I have a cone of height $h$, radius $r$, and mass $m$.

[image]

How can I determine the amount of force required to tip it over (to have it fall completely to the other side), say exerted (horizontally) at the top of the cone? And in addition, how does the position at which I exert the force affect the amount of force I will need to tip it over?

Any advice on how I would aproach this problem is appreciated.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou , *exerted (horizontally) at the top of the cone*

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Tipping occurs if there is a net moment about a point on the rim of the cone. The net moment is the sum of the moments due to the horizontally applied force and the weight of the cone acting through its center of gravity.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to start by locating the center of gravity (or mass). As the cone tips, that will move up along an arc centered on the tipping point, and the torques will decrease, and reach zero when the center of gravity is over the tipping point. For a minimum driving force, it should be applied at a right angle to the line joining the top and the tipping point.  You also need enough friction to keep the cone from sliding along the surface.

Answer (score 1):

For rotational static equilibrium, all torques about the CG must balance. Whatever amount of force is required to make the normal vector be applied at the rim of the cone is the load required for tipping.